# SQL - How to sort multiple table by common column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 table:

```
MariaDB [test]> DESCRIBE t1;
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | char(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time  | datetime  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


MariaDB [test]> DESCRIBE t2;
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | char(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time  | datetime  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


MariaDB [test]> DESCRIBE t3;
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | char(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time  | datetime  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to join 3 tables and sort all rows with `time` field.

How I can do this?

Comment: Do you really want to `join` those tables together or do you want to `union` them together?

Comment: I want to join. union removes duplicate rows.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify whaty ou want to do.

Comment: Problem has been solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT id, name, `time` FROM t1
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, name, `time` FROM t2
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, name, `time` FROM t3
ORDER BY `time`
```

The pattern where you have multiple tables with the same schema could indicate poor design.

Comment: this removes duplicate rows!

Comment: @chalist `UNION ALL` does not affect duplicates

Comment: @sagi `ORDER BY` will affect entire query

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a join you want a UNION:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT id, name, time FROM t1
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT id, name, time FROM t2
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT id, name, time FROM t3
 ) as dt
ORDER BY time
```

Comment: There is no need for subquery.

Comment: @lad2025 . . . Your answer is better and first.  I just don't think this one deserved a downvote, because it is also accurate (and I suspect for a sort, both methods materialize the intermediate results).

Comment: @lad2025 . . . Actually, it never crossed my mind that you would do that, especially without a comment.

Comment: @lad2025: In old versions of Standard SQL you were not allowed to use a column name for ORDER BY without Derived Table, only `ORDER BY 1` and I never liked using column numbers. So I'm just used to do it like this (and there are DBMSes, which require the Derived Table, e.g. Teradata)

Comment: If you mention `Teradata` there is one more case. Datatype is only taken from first `SELECT ... UNION ALL SELECT ...` so if there is `T1 col VARCHAR(50)` and `T2 col VARCHAR(100)` there will be truncation problem :)

Comment: @lad2025: Yep, that's a common source of "wrong results" :)